# Are there surprisingly identical binomial coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Suppose $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n'}{k'}$ with $k \geq 2$, $k' \geq 2$, $n \geq 2k$ and $n' \geq 2k'$. Does it follow that $n=n'$ and $k=k'$?

EDIT: Yup, $\binom{16}{2}=\binom{10}{3}=120$.

Now I want to ask if there are infinitely many such pairs, but I should probably ask that in a separate question. Thanks!

EDIT 2: for future reference, yes there are infinitely many such coincidences. See [Singmaster's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Rephrased: "Are there numbers in Pascal's triangle that are equal, apart from the obvious right-left symmetry?" I haven't checked, but I am convinced that there are quite a few.

Comment: A related question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17058/factorials-in-pascals-triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are one or two (nontrivial) choices of $(m,n)$ where $\binom{n}{2} = \binom{m}{3}$.   Comparing the sequences on OEIS might be faster than coming up with the correct words to find it in a search engine.

Edit: 120 is in both sequences, with $m=10$ and $n=16$.  In OEIS the list of triangular numbers ( http://oeis.org/A000217 ) and tetrahedral numbers ( http://oeis.org/A000292 ) shows that there are no other small examples and I am pretty sure that this pair is known to be the largest integer solution of $3y(y-1)=x(x-1)(x-2)$, and that this was first proved in an elementary way that does not use the theory of elliptic curves.

Comment: No, there are two more examples of ${n\choose2}={m\choose3}$. See https://oeis.org/A027568

Answer (score 8):

$$
\binom{3003}{1} = \binom{78}{2} = \binom{15}{5} = \binom{14}{6}.
$$

Nobody knows whether any number besides 3003 appears at least eight times in Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(t)$ be the number of ways in which $t$ can be written as a binomial coefficient. Then the question can be restated equivalently as asking whether $f(t) \leqslant 2$ for all $t$. As the other answers point out, there are numerous counterexamples to this strong claim.

It is however likely that a weaker form of this statement is true. [Singmaster's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster's_conjecture) states that there exists some $M \lt \infty$ such that $f(t) \leqslant M$ for all $t$. This is still open. The best known upper bound, due to D. Kane, is $$f(t) = O \left(\frac{(\log t) \cdot (\log \log \log t) }{(\log \log t)^3} \right) .$$ On the other hand, it is consistent with our current knowledge that $f(t)$ never exceeds $8$.

*Reference:* [This MO post by Michael Hardy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28717/) asks for recent progress on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

10-choose-4 = 21-choose-2.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\binom{10}{4} = \binom{21}{2}$ ?

Comment: Trying to guess what you meant, since it obviously isn't $\binom{10}{2}=\binom{21}{4}$...

Comment: ${10\choose 4} = {21 \choose 2}$

Comment: Oops. Miscopied from my source. Thanks for spotting the error and figuring out what I meant.

Comment: @Gerry I took the liberty to correct the typo. Hope it's ok. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{10}{3}=\binom{16}{2}.$$