# Are there infinitely many binomial coincidences?

Tags: number-theory

Atoning (I hope) for my silly [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/are-there-surprisingly-identical-binomial-coefficients), are there infinitely many equalities of the form $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n'}{k'}$ with $k,k' \geq 2$, $n \geq 2k$, $n' \geq 2k'$ and $n \neq n'$?

EDIT: According to the Wikipedia article on [Singmaster's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture), yes there are: there are infinitely many solutions to $\binom{n}{k+2}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Sorry for the spam.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer the question yourself so that it does not remain unanswered.  I think I first saw the conjecture here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75698/examples-of-seemingly-elementary-problems-that-are-hard-to-solve/75721#757217

Comment: The link to the article about Singmaster's conjecture is probably as good an answer to this question as anybody knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as not to leave the question unanswered: Yes, there are infinitely many such coincidences. An infinite family is given by

$\binom{n}{k+2} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$

with $n = F_{2i+2}F_{2i+3}-1$, $k = F_{2i}F_{2i+3}-1$ and $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence indexed such that $F_1=F_2=1$.