# How can I find the first occurrence of a number in Pascal's triangle?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to efficiently(ie: without building the actual triangle) to find out which row a number first occurs in in Pascal's triangle?

This is equivalent to answering: given `A` what is the smallest number `m` such that there exists `n` such that `m choose n = A`. This is due to the fact that a number at row `m` and column `n` in Pascal's triangle is equal to `m choose n`.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/how-to-reverse-the-n-choose-k-formula/103385#103385

Comment: Apply the algorithm described in the link above, but start with the largest value of $k$ first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link provided by JavaMan indeed answers this question: [How to reverse the $n$ choose $k$ formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/how-to-reverse-the-n-choose-k-formula/103385#103385)

A summary of the algorithm -- took me while to figure out from that answer, so I'm writing it as an algorithm instead of an explanation of one. If you want to know how this works, I highly recommend visiting that answer and upvoting it, it's very informative -- is as follows. First, the problem is minimizing `n` given `X` such that:

$${n \choose k} = X$$

First we determine `max(k)` given that we know that:
$$X > \frac{4^k}{2k+1}$$

From there we iterate over `1 to max(k)`. At each step of the iteration, `n`, if it exists is contained in the interval:

$$\sqrt[k]{k! X} + k \ge n \ge \sqrt[k]{k! X}$$

We iterate over that interval and check if ${n \choose k}=X$. We can then easily find the minimum such `n`.