# Inverse/Reverse of Number of Permutations and of Number of Combinations with Repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients, inverse-function

For an engineering application, I need the inverse functions of the computations of the number of combinations and permutations.

In the thread [How to reverse the $n$ choose $k$ formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/how-to-reverse-the-n-choose-k-formula) it shows how to reverse/inverse the number of combinations function...

Given:

$X = C(n, k) = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n! }{ k!(n-k)! }$

then you can limit n to:

$\sqrt[k]{k! X} + k \ge n \ge \sqrt[k]{k! X}$

And thus you at most need to check k+1 possible values of n (or with a binary search, just log(k+1) checks). Great!

**But how do I solve for k instead of for n? (Given n and the number of combinations, how do I compute k?)**

And given instead number of Permutations:

$X = P(n, k) = \frac{n! }{ (n-k)! }$

then I believe I am correct in assuming from above that:

$\sqrt[k]{X} + k \ge n \ge \sqrt[k]{X}$

And in this case, I actually can solve for k as well since k only appears once:

$k = n - InverseLnFactorial(ln(n!) - ln(X))$

And finally, given instead CR is Combinations with Repetitions:

$X = CR(n, k) = \binom{n+k-1}{k} = \binom{n+k-1}{n-1} = \frac{ (n+k-1)! }{ k!(n-1)! }$

then I believe I am correct in assuming from above that:

$\sqrt[k]{k! X} \ge n \ge \sqrt[k]{k! X} - k$

**But again, how would I then solve for k instead of n? (Given n and the number of combinations with repetitions, how would I compute k?)**

In both cases of Combinations (with and without repetitions), having k appear inside two different factorial terms makes it difficult for me to find an algebraic way to solve for k.  Any help, or even clue, on how to do the algebra for those two cases would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question: when we are solving for $k$, is $n$ fixed?

Comment: Yes, @Eevee Trainer, when solving for k, you can assume n is fixed/known.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the algorithm you linked; it is not solving for just $n$, it solving for $k$ and $n$ simultaneously. So the code given there takes care of your first problem.

Comment: Also your last problem; given the value $X$ in $X=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$, apply the $C$-inverse algorithm to find $m,k$ so $X=\binom{m}{k}$, then let $n=m-k+1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, I've re-read that link a couple times... it is just giving a way to bound 'n' and then compute it, given you know k and the number of combinations.  In general, it is impossible to solve for n and k simultaneously... you have to know one to compute the other.  That link shows how, given you know k, you can compute the matching 'n' by bounding it to at most k different values, and then test each by computing the number of combinations and seeing if it gives the right value.  Computing 'k' when 'n' and the number of combinations are known is still a mystery.

Comment: **Reversing $C(n,k)$**

We know that $C(n,k)=\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}{1.2.3\dots k}$
To compute $k$ in $k$ steps, let
$$ X_0=X \\
X_1=\frac{X_0}{n}\\
X_2=\frac{2X_1}{n-1}\\
X_3=\frac{3X_2}{n-2}\\ \vdots  $$

If $X_i>1$, compute $X_{i+1}$. When $X_i=1$, we know that $k=i$ and $k=n-i$ are the desired solutions.

**Reversing RC(n,k)**

This time, $RC(n,k)=\frac{n(n+1)\dots (n+k-1)}{1.2.3\dots k}$. Let
$$ X_0=X \\
X_1=\frac{X_0}{n}\\
X_2=\frac{2X_1}{n+1}\\
X_3=\frac{3X_2}{n+2}\\ \vdots  $$

If $X_i>1$, compute $X_{i+1}$. When $X_i=1$, $k=i$ is the desired solution.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson, thanks for that suggestion. But I'll need something a bit more efficient than that since k can be large.  However, building on your suggestion, I need to find where the falling factorial n(k) is equal to X * k!.  If I can approximately compute both of those, I could perhaps do a binary search to find the right k value.  I'll have to research the quality and efficiency of approximations of falling factorials.  Hmmm.

Comment: I don’t understand how you can solve $\sqrt[k]{X} + k \ge n \ge \sqrt[k]{X}$ for $k$ and why $k = n - InverseLnFactorial(ln(n!) - ln(X))$. In particular, I don’t see $n!$ in the initial inequality.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, you wouldn't solve the bounds for 'n' to get 'k'... you'd solve the original equation X = n! / (n-k)! ... so, (n-k)! = n! / X ... and thus ln((n-k)!) = ln(n!) - ln(X) ... and thus n-k = InverseLnFactorial(ln(n!) - ln(X))... and finally k = n - InverseLnFactorial(ln(n!) - ln(X)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find $k$ by a binary search as follows.

It is easy to check that when $n$ is sufficiently big and fixed and $k$ increases in its range, $X$ increases too. Namely, it holds uder the following assumptions.

- If $X=C(n,k)$, then we assume that $n\ge 1$, $k\ge 0$ and, since $C(n,k)=C(n,n-k)$, $k\le n/2$.
- If $X=P(n,k)$ then we assume that $n\ge 2$ and $0\le k\le n$.
- If $X=CR(n,k)$ then we assume that $n\ge 3$ and $k\ge 0$.

So we can look for $k$ first by an increasing binary search, trying $k=0,1,2,4,\dots$ until $C(n,k)>X$ and then by a decreasing binary search.

We can improve this algorithm by providing lower bounds for $k$.

Namely, if $X$ is $C(n,k)$ or $P(n,k)$ then $X\le n^k$, so $k\ge \ln X/\ln n$. A bit better bound can be obtained as follows. Since $\ln (1+x) \le x$ for any $x>-1$,

$$\ln X\le \ln\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} n-i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln(n-i)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln \left(n\left(1-\frac in\right)\right)=$$ $$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln n +\ln \left(1-\frac in\right)\le k\ln n - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac in= k\ln n-\frac {k(k-1)}{2n}.$$

Thus 
$$k\ge n\ln n+\frac 12-\sqrt{\left(n\ln n+\frac 12\right)^2-2n\ln X}>\frac{\ln X}{\ln n+\tfrac 1{2n}} .$$

For $X=CR(n,k)$ we similarly obtain

$$\ln X\le \ln\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} n+i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln(n+i)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln \left(n\left(1+\frac in\right)\right)=$$ $$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \ln n +\ln \left(1+\frac in\right)\le k\ln n + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac in= k\ln n+\frac {k(k-1)}{2n}.$$

Thus

$$k\ge -n\ln n+\frac 12+\sqrt{\left(n\ln n-\frac 12\right)^2+2n\ln X}.$$

Comment: Thanks for working out those bounds... it'll take me a bit to work through that math to verify, but this definitely appears to be a workable solution.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it give a usable answer for both with repetitions and without repetitions.  I awarded the bounty to tomi's answer because it gave a far more efficient approximation... but only works for the without repetitions case... and I haven't found a way to extend that for the other.  Thanks again, Alex!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I started by considering the graph of $y=_nC_x$ - illustrated above.

I then looked at the natural logarithm - after all, Stirling's formula gives factorials as powers.

[image]

This curve looks like a quadratic, so I tried to fit a quadratic of the form $y=x(n-x)$.

[image]

You can see that this is not quite right. I therefore tried variations of the form $y=\left(x(n-x)\right)^p$ until I found a good fit with $p={3 \over 4}$

[image]

I don't know why this works, but it seems to. I'll now work on creating an inverse function, which should be quite easy.

We have the relationship $\ln(_nC_k) \approx ak^{3 \over 4}(n-k)^{3 \over 4}$

where $a=\frac{\ln\left(_nC_{n \over 2}\right)}{\left({n \over 2}\right)^{3 \over 4}\left({n \over 2}\right)^{3 \over 4}}$

$k^{3 \over 4}(n-k)^{3 \over 4}=\frac{\ln\left(_nC_k\right)}a $

$k(n-k)=\left(\frac{\ln\left(_nC_k\right)}a\right)^{4 \over 3} $

Let's call this $k(n-k)=b$, where $b=\left(\frac{\ln\left(_nC_k\right)}a\right)^{4 \over 3} $

Then $kn-k^2=b$ can be rewritten $k^2-kn+b=0$

$k_1=\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-4b}}{2}$

$k_2=\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4b}}{2}$

I've tested this and the values it gives for $k$ are pretty close - probably only need to test integers one or two above and below the value of $k_1$.

I would really appreciate an explanation of why this works!

*An explanation, why this works by Alex Ravsky.*

By Stirling’s formula, for each natural $m$ there exists a number $0<\theta<1$ such that $$m!=\sqrt{2\pi m}\left(\frac me\right)^m e^{\frac \theta{12m}}.$$ Thus 
$$\ln(m!)=\tfrac12(\ln 2+\ln\pi+\ln m)+m(\ln m - 1)+O\left(\frac {1}{m}\right).$$

Let $k=\lambda n$ for $0<\lambda<1$. Then

$$\ln {n \choose k}=\ln \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=$$ 
$$n(\ln n-1)- k(\ln k-1)-(n-k)(\ln (n-k)-1)+\frac 12(\ln n-\ln k-\ln (n-k))+O(1)=$$
$$n\ln n- k\ln k-(n-k)\ln (n-k)+\frac 12(\ln n-\ln k-\ln (n-k))+O(1)=$$
$$n\ln n- \lambda n (\ln\lambda+\ln n) -(1-\lambda)n(\ln(1-\lambda)+\ln n)+
\frac 12(\ln n-\ln\lambda-\ln n-\ln (1-\lambda)-\ln n)+O(1)=$$
$$ - \lambda n \ln\lambda -(1-\lambda)n\ln(1-\lambda)-\frac 12(\ln n+\ln\lambda+\ln (1-\lambda))+O(1)=$$
$$\left(n-\frac 12\right)f(\lambda)-\frac 12\ln n+O(1),$$

where $f(\lambda)=- \lambda \ln\lambda -(1-\lambda) \ln(1-\lambda) $.

The graphs below suggest that a function $g(\lambda)=2\sqrt{2}\ln (2)(\lambda(1-\lambda))^{3/4}$ is an extremely good approximation of $f(\lambda)$.

[image]

[image]

PS. Maybe we also can similarly obtain approximations of $\ln CR(n,k)$ and $\ln P(n,k)$ using some functions depending on $\lambda=k/n$. Remark that for $CR(n,k)$ case we allow $\lambda>1$.

Comment: This is an amazing post... getting to watch the formulation of one of those approximations where it seems "magic happens here".  I am implementing this now so that I can more thoroughly test its accuracy.  Two questions for you, while I do that:
(1)  Can you use this same approximation to solve for 'n' such that I can avoid the binary search within the bounds that I am having to do now?
(2)  Can you create a similar formulation for Combinations with Repetitions?
I'll be attacking those questions myself once I prove out this much.  In any case, thanks so much!!!

Comment: So far the answer to both those questions is ‘No,’ but I will work on them both.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the three different cases $$X = \frac{n! }{ k!(n-k)! }=\frac{ n!}{\Gamma(k+1)\, \Gamma(n+1-k)}$$ $$ X =\frac{n! }{ (n-k)! } =\frac{ n!}{\Gamma(n+1-k)}$$ $$X= \frac{ (n+k-1)! }{ k!(n-1)! }=\frac{ \Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(k+1)\, n!}$$ I should look, in the real domain, for the zero of functions
$$F(k)=\log (\Gamma (k+1))+\log (\Gamma (n+1-k))-\log \left(\frac{n!}{X}\right)\tag 1$$
$$G(k)=\log (\Gamma (n+1-k))-\log \left(\frac{n!}{X}\right) \tag 2$$ 
$$H(k)=\log (\Gamma (k+n)) -\log (\Gamma (k+1))-\log \left({n!}{X}\right)\tag 3$$since function  *lngamma(x)* is available almost everywhere.

For $(2)$, there is a superb approximation given on this site by @robjohn(have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial/2079043#2079043)). This would provide you a very good *estimate* of $k$.

Since Alex Ravsky provided  lower bounds, I should retain these as $k_0$ and start Newton iterations using numerical derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, Claude.  I'm hoping I'll be able to avoid Newton iterations; but yes, that is a workable solution.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BrianKennedy. You are very welcome ! I think that Newton would be the easiest way (because of the availability of *lngamma(x)* function)