# Number of integral solutions to elliptic curve $\binom n2=\binom m3$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I am wondering if there are infinitely many integral solutions to the equation: 
$$ {n \choose 2} = {m \choose 3}. $$
Also, do the solutions have a general form? 
From what I know, this is an elliptic curve, but I don't have much knowledge about elliptic curves. If this problem is solvable using standard methods, I would also like to have a reference for learning about elliptic curves.

Comment: Are you interested in rational points? Or integer points?

Comment: @hardmath integer points.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/are-there-surprisingly-identical-binomial-coefficients and the links there.

Comment: Have you followed up on this, Quasi?

Comment: Are you still here, Quasi?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson what do you mean by follow up?

Comment: I mean, did you go to the link and read what was there? Did you go to the links at that link and read them? Did you find anything of relevance to the question you asked here?

Comment: So, followed up, Quasi?

Answer (score 7):

Clearing the denominators and multiplying everything by $3^3=27$ yields the equivalent equation
$$81n^2-81n=27m^3-81m^2+54m.\tag{1}$$
Now by setting $y:=9n-5$ and $x:=3m-3$ we get the minimal Weierstrass equation
$$y^2+y=x^3-9x+20,\tag{2}$$
which defines an elliptic curve because its [discriminant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticDiscriminant.html) is nonzero. Note that if $(m,n)$ is an integral solution to $(1)$, then $(x,y):=(3m-3,9n-5)$ is an integral solution to $(2)$. By [Siegel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points) an elliptic curve with rational coefficients has only finitely many integral points. The integral points of $(2)$ are 
$$(−3,4),\ 
(-2,5),\ 
(0,4),\ 
(1,3),\ 
(3,4),\ 
(6,13),\ 
(10,30),\ 
(12,40),\ 
(27,139),\ 
(63,499),\ 
(105,1075).$$
These correspond to the following solutions $(m,n)$ to $(1)$:
$$(0,1),\ 
(\tfrac13,\tfrac{10}{9}),\ 
(1,1),\ 
(\tfrac43,\tfrac89),\ 
(2,1),\ 
(3,2),\ 
(\tfrac{13}{3},\tfrac{35}{9}),\ 
(5,5),\ 
(10,16),\ 
(22,56),\ 
(36,120).$$

---

In general, finding *all* integral points on an elliptic curve is not an easy task. There are computer packages that can do this for you, if the coefficients of the Weierstrass equation are not too large. There is also the [$L$-functions and Modular Forms Database](http://www.lmfdb.org/), which is where I found the integral points of this particular curve; see [this page](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1611/a/1).

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend me a good book/reference about elliptic curves? I only have a background in some abstract algebra and I'm starting to learn Algebraic NT. What would be some other prerequisites?

Comment: @Quasi07 Other prerequisites are some basic algebraic geometry, and before that commutative algebra, which you will also need for algebraic number theory. I can recommend the classic *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and Macdonald.

Comment: I was introduced to elliptic curves myself by Silverman's book *Rational points on Elliptic Curves*, which I quite liked. It has a chapter on integral points on elliptic curves as well.

Comment: Can you show me the steps you used to get to (1)?